# Auto Open Modal on New Page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Upon a user entering a new page, I'd like a modal to immediately appear above the page.

Is there a specific method to accomplish this in jQuery Mobile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to one of the `page-events` that jQuery mobile exposes. If you want to show the dialog every time a page is shown then you can use `pageshow` or if you want it to only display the first time a user views a page you can use `pageinit`. Here is a full list of events made available by jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Here's a quick example of binding to the `pageinit` event for every page:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {
    //now call the code to show the dialog
});
```

I used `.delegate()` because a page may not exist in the DOM at the time that this binding occurs.